# Pourquoi "bien" au lieu de "bons"?

Tags: choix-de-mot

J'ai une question. Dans la phrase suivante, pourquoi utilise-t-on "bien" au lieu de "bons"? *Les grands magasins et les hypermarchés sont **bien**, mais nous préférons fréquenter les petits commerces qui sont encore tenus par une seule famille.*

Comment: P.S. *au lieu de* (will delete after edit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually a part of an idiomatic French expression that translates as something along the lines of "it's all very **well** doing ..., but ..." in English. In French, you can express this idea in several different ways. e.g.:

> C'est **bien** joli de faire ..., mais ...
>
> C'est **bien** beau tout ça, mais ...
>
> Faire ... c’est **bien** gentil, mais ...

... whereas the adjective "bon" would refer to the quality of those shops.

---

Your example can be paraphrased as:

> Les grands magasins et les hypermarchés, c'est **bien**, mais ...
>
> Les grands magasins et les hypermarchés, c'est **bien** (tout) ça, mais ...

Comment: Actually, they are not strictly equivalent. *"X c'est bien (tout ça), mais"* has an ironic / sarcastic meaning that *"X sont bien, mais"* doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Parce que les deux ont un sens voisin mais différent.

> Les hypermarchés sont bons

voudrait dire, éventuellement par métonymie, que l'organisation des hypermarchés est efficace ou leurs employés, compétents, ou que les (aliments vendus dans les) hypermarchés ont bon goût.

> Les hypermarchés sont bien

[Bien](http://stella.atilf.fr/Dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/visusel.exe?12;s=3024875025;r=1;nat=;sol=1;) peut signifier tout un tas de choses positives mais dans le contexte, il s'agit d'une appréciation globale et assez indéfinie de la valeur de ces magasins pour un client.